# Build failure with warning message for my first blank app of apache cordova

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to build my first blank app of apache cordova. I got no error but the build was failed with the following warning message. Any idea what went wrong here? Thanks.

```
> 1>------ Build started: Project: AngularJSToDo, Configuration: Debug Android ------
> 1>C:\Program Files    (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targe     ts(95,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  GeneratedJavascript=
1>  c:\Cordova\AngularJSToDo\AngularJSToDo>call "C:\Program   Files\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.0 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\WERYROUC.GOP\packages\vs-mda
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-mda
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 0.1.70
1>  ------ Current globally installed version: 0.1.70
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Based on your   log message  `TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling` may be this will help .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945921/the-typescript-compiler-was-given-no-files-for-compilation-so-it-will-skip-comp.

Comment: Not really. I'm using javascript project and no typescript files to be built. But not sure why I got this warning message and can't get rid of it as well.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. I added a simple.ts file with an empty module inside it to remove the warning from typescript.  I'm still getting a 1 failed result but no other hints.  Is there a more verbose build option?

Comment: You can set your build output verbosity to Diagnostic via Tools\Options\Projects and Solutions\Build and Run\MSBuild project build output verbosity.  After doing this, perform a clean build and examine the build output to diagnose the error.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the post that shammon linked to, this warning is harmless in a JavaScript app.

Comment: yes, but as you can see from the output message, the build was failed for somehow with this warning message. And no emulator was appeared on the screen. It just didn't work.