# PhoneGap project does not run on Android phone and Ripple (Error : EPERM, open .....)

Tags: android, cordova, typescript, phonegap-plugins

I have created a new project in VisualStudio 2013, when i run it on windows emulator and device it works fine, but when I run it on Ripple and Android phones it does not run and gives me 1 Error and 1 Warning.

> Warning   1   The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation,
>   so it will skip compiling.     Error  2   EPERM, open
>   'C:\Users\rao.burugula.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package.tgz'

When I looked for package.tgz it was a zip file so I unzipped and placed it there. but still its the same issue.

Other PhoneGap projects work fine which are created in VS2013, only the new ones I create get this error.

Could you please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Following the code which is auto generated when I create a new Blank App (Apache Cordova).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>TestRestWebservices</title>
   <!-- TestRestWebservices references -->
   <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
   <p>Hello, your application is ready!</p>
   <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
   <script src="cordova.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Update:**
I also tried using this 
[The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945921/the-typescript-compiler-was-given-no-files-for-compilation-so-it-will-skip-comp)

but could not find the 'build action' for any typescript files. I looked in properties but none there. Path to locate it ??
Thanks in advance

Rao

Comment: possible duplicate of [The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945921/the-typescript-compiler-was-given-no-files-for-compilation-so-it-will-skip-comp)

Comment: I tried having a look at it but could not find the 'build action' in properties tab of the .js files. could you suggest where can i find the 'build action'