# Why can't I compile Apache Cordova project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I'm having this warning and this error. Do you know why ?

[image]

I read this [The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945921/the-typescript-compiler-was-given-no-files-for-compilation-so-it-will-skip-comp)

but I'm still stuck.

I've checked this also :

[image]

I've uninstalled visual studio and reinstall , and I'm getting the same result.
I've installed VS2013 with ApacheCordova tools on my laptop, and I'm getting the same result.

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you have any .ts files in your project with Compile Action = TypeScriptCompile?

Comment: I have 0 file with .ts

Comment: I have just created a .ts file and the warning is gone...(lol). But the error is still here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this warning you can remove the `<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />` line in your `.csproj` file (in this case it might be a `.jsproj` btw). You can just open this in your favorite text editor.

Offcourse if you plan to use TypeScript you can always add it back in.

edit:

About the second part of your error, can you post the output from the output window, you might see what is going on there.

If that doesn't give you enough information you can open "Tools" -> "Options" and on the left side go to "Projects and solutions" and select "Build and Run". If you change the MSBuild project build output verbosity to "Diagnostic" you might find something there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the second error is my fault, I wanted to copy/paste an already done project directly and it throws error. However if i create a new project and launch it on my device, it works. So the error isn't related to software installation but with code